Remove direct access to mysql
Due to a damaged partition I had to migrate my projects to another partition on which I installed linuxmint which in turn installed mysql Ver 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1. This mysql installation allows access, from the terminal, without asking for a user or password and this is not good for my projects or for programs like valentinaDB or DBeaver that I often use. I searched everywhere but no solution was the right one.
I recently found a solution that consisted of doing a certain type of mysql installation during which both user and password were asked, but I no longer remember how I did it

Have you tried with ALTER USER yourUser IDENTIFIED BY 'yourPasswordHere'; ?

I tried but nothing changed.
I have access to the corrupted partition and was wondering if it is possible to copy /var/lib/mysql from the old partition to the new one. Or change datadir in mysql.conf.d to point to the old partition.
Is this possible?

Well, I tried my own suggestions and

changing data dir doesn't work. mysql exit with error
moving the old /var/lib/mysq to the new location has no effect, I don't need user-psw to access mysql


Solved the problem by issuing
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'my_password';

previously was auth_socket

mysql_native_password it is depracated and it might be removed in future releases. Is there a specifc reason to use it?

Yes. If I don't change auth_socket to mysql_native_password  anyone from the command line can access my databases while from my projects or Valentinadb or DBeaver I am not allowed to.
As for future mysql releases, I don't think I'll be bothered. This one does everything I need.
